How can I use a custom DNS server for all the clients in my VPN subnet?
My wireguard server has a DNS server to expose domain name for all my VPN clients.
What's the best way to do that? I'd like to manually modify the names only in the server, so that if I add one more client, all the clients will have the IP address up-to-date automatically.
My client .conf:
[Interface]
Address = 10.1.0.4/32
PrivateKey = XXXX
DNS = 10.1.0.1

Once running, it overwrites /etc/resolv.conf
# This file was generated by wg-quick(8) for use with
# the WireGuard interface wgaws. It cannot be
# removed or altered directly. You may remove this file
# by running `wg-quick down wgaws', or if that
# poses problems, run `umount /etc/resolv.conf'.

nameserver 10.1.0.1

It removes all my local nameservers generated by NetworkManager.
How to instruct wireguard to add the nameserver, not replacing them?
Here is my current /etc/resolv.conf without any wireguard interface up:
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.123.1
nameserver 192.168.111.1


Your question is quite unclear in a number of respects.   Some questions - are your clients running Linux?  Is your nameserver both authorative and recusive?     How do you see multiple nameservers working - I don't think DNS resolution works the way you think it does.

Without wireguard, I have 3 DNS servers listed. I'd like to have one DNS server that handles only my VPN's domain names and let the others handling everything else. Is it possible? DNS servers aren't requested with priorities? (if domain name doesn't exist in the first server, ask the 2nd and so on)

if domain name doesn't exist in the first server, ask the 2nd and so on) - this is not generally correct - although it somewhat depends on the combination of software used on both sides and how they handle failures, and can be the practical outcome.   Generally the solution would be to make the server 10.1.0.1 handle both authorative and recursive queries.  Very often this is done using DNSMASQ as the nameserver - this has a lot of flexibility around just this type of job, and is available with most variants of Linux.

oh ok, I must read much more about DNS then... clients have their own dns server, I don't want to force a dns server to these clients. I want to advertise only the names related to the VPN.

I delete the question and open a new one after some research! Thanks!

If having a longish domain can work you can always register a domain, then set up each of the clients as subdomains and use some kind of dynamic DNS mechanism and low TTL - or assign the IP's of the clients statically.

the IPs are already assigned and won't change (wireguard), I just need a way to advertise a name for each of them. mmmh, indeed it's a solution but out of curiosity, I'd like to achieve that without having a public domain

That might be difficult unless you can intercept the DNS queries or get the clients DNS resolvers to look to your nameserver for an internal domain.
